# How to print last character of a file

Tags: unix, sed

In Unix, using a simple command like sed, is there a way to print the last character of a file?

Comment: Do you care if the last character is actually "printable"?  i.e. if the last character is a new line, is that ok?

Answer (score 43):

tail is the right tool, not sed.

```
tail -c 1 filename
```

Comment: +1 - For a text file, if you want the last character before the last newline, just replace 1 by 2

Answer (score 8):

`tail -c 2 file` should do it. Should be -c 1 in theory but practice proved me wrong.

Edit:
If your file has a an end of line character that you want to ignore, it's 2. 1 otherwise.

Comment: Maybe your test file has a newline at the end?

Comment: It indeed had one.

Comment: I've never seen a file with an *end of life* character.

Comment: @PaulR Perhaps it's just a file so long when you arrive at the end you're dead :D

Answer (score 4):

Try this `cat filename | tail -c -1`

Comment: Heh, first time I've ever seen "Your answer must be at least 30 characters".

Comment: misuse of pipes, same pitfall as in **cat foo | grep bar**

Comment: @vtest: What are those pitfalls?

Comment: @vtest, maybe "Try this `tail -c -1 filename`" was too short answer (less than 30 chars), so additional `cat |` was added to prolong it. `;)`

Comment: @ulidtko: I commented on the recipe, not on the answer length

Comment: @vtest That misuse was probably to get the answer above the 30 character limit

Comment: **Indulging in the "useless use of cat"-award is just useless nitpicking.**  `cat file | cmd` **does not fail in normal circumstances** (`set +o pipefail`) when `file` is missing while `cmd < file` can even make your shell bail out (`set -e`) if `file` is missing.  So there are good reasons to use it, and there are good reasons to avoid it.  Both!  Hence **`cat | grep` per-se isn't a misuse** and also not a bad habbit!  Imagine `cat | cat | cat | cat | cat | cat | cat | cat | cat | cat | cat | cat | cat | cmd`.  If you can't think of a reason for this, think again!  Hint: `tac | tac | cmd`

Answer (score 1):

by '*last char*' - do you mean last *letter* or last *byte*?

Usually a text file is ended with LF (or CRLF in Win), so tail -c1 will return that ending cbyte of the file.

to get last '*letter-char*' one can filter special chars first, and then get last char:

```
tail -1 filename| tr -d "\r\n" | tail -c1
tail -c9 filename| tr -d "\r\n" | tail -c1
```

where

- `tail -1` - at 1st get last line, actually getting few chars also will do `tail -c9` fo this task
- `tr -d "\r\n"`  - strip EOL special chars if there are,
- `tail -c1` - finally get last byte, which is last letter-char.

P.S. also, if you need to test whether a file is ended with LF, it is easier to do after converting last byte to hex code:

```
tail -c1 file.csv | xxd -p
0a
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work, provided that last line is not empty:

```
sed -n '$s/.*\(.\)$/\1/p' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Use: `cat test | sed -e "s/^.*\(.\)$/\1/"`

where test is the name of your file.

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of the reader:

### The problem

There is some misconception here.  While **`tail -c1 file`** indeed is the correct command to print the last character of a file, **this cannot be used easily to detect if a file ends on `NL` from shell level**, due to how POSIX-shells process command outputs:

```
if last_character="$(tail -c1 "$file")"; then ..
# WRONG! last_character will be empty on NL, as well as on an empty file
```

For some unknown reason POSIX defines, that **all trailing NLs are stripped** if you catch some command's output.  Note that nearly all shell scripts out there fall into this trap on even the most simple things like

```
cd "$(dirname -- "$0")" || exit           # Wrong, see: mkdir $'\n'
base="$(basename -- "$0" .sh)" || exit    # Wrong, see: mv script.sh $'\n.sh'
```

Attackers might even exploit this POSIX standard using softlinks!

### How to solve this .. NOT

> Please note that I use `bash` version 4 syntax here.

You can do things like this:

```
set -o pipefail
if tail -c1 file | { IFS= read -rd '' var; postprocess "$var"; }; then ..
```

But this is a PITA due to the subshell.  Or

```
6< <(tail -c1 file) IFS= read -ru6 -d '' var
```

which is even likewise weird.  (How to properly detect failure of `tail` here, etc.)

### How to solve this the right way

But following recipe usually works:

```
var="$(tail -c1 file && echo x)" && var="${var%x}" || error ..
```

For commands which always add an extra NL (nearly all commands do this, like `basename` or `dirname`), you need to adapt this to:

```
var="$(basename -- "$file" && echo x)" && var="${var%$'\nx'}" || error ..
#----------------------------------------------------^^^^^^ change
```

Note that this recipe also works in other normal circumstances:

```
# This is only correct here because we only expect a single filename
echo wrong > $'file'
echo right > $'file\n'
wrongname="$(fgrep -lx right file*)" || notfound
correctname="$(fgrep -lx right file* && echo x)" && correctname="${correctname%$'\nx'}" || notfound
```

`wrongname` will contain `file` while `correctname` will contain `file\n` (where `\n` stands for `NL`).  As both files exist and contain data, you probably won't spot the error quickly, that you used the `wrongname` variant with the file with the wrong content.

Yes, a bit finicking, but nevertheless sometimes needed.